# How to set fade timer in Jquery with HTML input?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a < div > That needs to fade in it will have a input box with the correct settings for timer. But i want to set it when it restarts so it fades in and out with that speed in js?

Comment: Could you be more clear and maybe use a little more punctuation.  Also, pasting in some code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.fadeOut` and `$.fadeIn` functions take a parameter of the duration for the fade animation.  You can use the `.val()` function on the input box and pass that as an attribute.

Example:

```
<div id="target" style="display:none;">Hello World!</div>
<input id="duration" value="1000" />
<button>Click To Show!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('#target').fadeIn($('#duration').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var speed = $('#element').val();

$('#another-element').fadeIn('fast').delay(speed).fadeOut('fast');
```